# onHoverListener doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, onhover

In android document, it mentions supporting the "hover" event since 4.0 (ie. API level 14 and up). But somehow, it doesn't work. Even I tried out the sample code in ApiDemo, which is from Android Sample, it didn't work. 
My current device is Android 4.0.4. Should I upgrade it to 4.2.2?

Sample code is something as below.
Did you have a solution to it? Thanks a lot.

Code:

---

```
View container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                    mMessageTextView.setText(Hover.this.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.hover_message_entered_at,
                            event.getX(), event.getY()));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
                    mMessageTextView.setText(Hover.this.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.hover_message_moved_at,
                            event.getX(), event.getY()));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                    mMessageTextView.setText(Hover.this.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.hover_message_exited_at,
                            event.getX(), event.getY()));
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

---

Answer (score 10):

Hovering requires support from the hardware.  The only thing likely to support it is a stylus.  It won't work with just your finger.

Comment: Thanks. Will it work with mouse? e.g. a bluetooth mouse compatible with Android device?

Comment: Not sure, I've never tried it.  I think it might (a non-clicked mouse as a hover makes sense), but I can't swear it will.

Comment: As an update to this-  some devices will now be able to detect a single finger hovering.  But really only the higher end devices, like the Note.  You can't rely on it.

Comment: I tried the code on android emulator, it didn't work on that using mouse. Have someone else tried and got it working ?

Answer (score 1):

try using `OnFocusChangeListener()`. 
PS worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to Turn on 'Accessibility' and 'Explore by touch' feature in settings.
When these features are off, the hover action will be treated as touch actions.

Answer (score 0):

**setOnTouchListener is also an option. Here is a kotlin example:**

```
    binding.ratingBar.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        println("touch......")
        false
    }
```

here (binding.ratingBar) is my view reference. I used view binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug on a Chromebook, Alternatively, If you do not have one like me, Install [fydeOS](https://fydeos.io/) over a VMware station. Enable debugging mode on `fydeOS` so you can debug your app using android studio. If you do everything right, You will see the fydeOS device on the android studio device manager list.

**Note:** fydeOS has separated *image for WMware* and supported hardwares. see [here](https://openfyde.io/)

[image]