# Android select multiple ImageView onTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch-event

I have a 3*3 imageviews in a tablelayout.

A A A

A A A

A A A

suppose I touch on (0,0) image and then swipe to the (0,2) image passing through (0,1) image in a single touch.
the images supposed to be

B B B

A A A

A A A

To be concise: I want every images I pass through will change to another image.

Is there anyone knows how to deal with such events? Thanks a lot!

In addition, can anybody explain why onHoverListener doesn't work?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding onTouchEvent for each imageView.
But only the one onTouch can invoke.
Those image passed through wont invoke onTouch event.

Comment: Can't work. It seems that onHoverListener only work in mouse / touchpen onhover event.
see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909495/onhoverlistener-doesnt-work-in-android