# Button - sound - onHoverListener - tiger

Tags: android, button, audio, onhover

What do I need to do to make my button (or sth else, please tell me what should
i use):

> - Start playing music on `ACTION_HOVER_ENTER`
> - Keep playing (without reset, just do nothing) on `ACTION_HOVER_MOVE`
> - Stop playing and reset music on `ACTION_HOVER_EXIT`
> - Work when I start my move from anywhere on the screen, then without release `hover enter` my button
> - Have no problem with starting the same activity but triggered by another button located in another part of the screen - without finger's release

I should use `onHoverListener()`, am I right?

Please write code sample if you can :)

Here is what do I have so far:

```
package com.example.android.appname;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView b1;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
    b1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(DisplayActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
            switch (event.getAction()) {


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                    if (mPlayer == null)
                        mPlayer.start();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                    mPlayer.release();
                    mPlayer = null;
                    break;
            }
            return false;

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This isn't a place where you ask people to write code for you. We're here to help answer questions and solve problems for people who've put in the effort to try themselves.

Comment: I am just looking for some help, because I was writing my code for a long time, it is still not working, so I decided to look for an advice on this forum.

Comment: Just added my work, @mwieczorek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try implementing this way**

It would require you to tell the System that you've consumed the Event and interested in consumption of successive Events. This can be done by returning `true` (expressing interest), `false` (expressing no interested).

```
@Override
public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(DisplayActivity.this, R.raw.sound);

    // Flag to indicate interest
    boolean consumable = false;

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
            if (mPlayer == null) {
                mPlayer.start();
                consumable = true;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
            consumable = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
            consumable = true;
            break;
    }

    return consumable;
}
```

Note: [There might be Hardware Limitations to detect any `Hover`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909551/6213557)