# Android setOnHoverListener for view is not working on emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, hover, mouseover

I just downloaded android api samples, inside com.example.android.apis.view.Hover.java i just clicked to check if android emulator which had API level 19 should detect onhover but it didn't. Has someone else faced this issue ?

```
 View container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                    mMessageTextView.setText(Hover.this.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.hover_message_entered_at,
                            event.getX(), event.getY()));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
                    mMessageTextView.setText(Hover.this.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.hover_message_moved_at,
                            event.getX(), event.getY()));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                    mMessageTextView.setText(Hover.this.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.hover_message_exited_at,
                            event.getX(), event.getY()));
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here is the piece of code i am talking about.

What kind of support from hardware ? If i can get onTouchEvent from my mouse pointer in android emulator, shouldn't i get onHover event as well ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onHoverListener doesn't work in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909495/onhoverlistener-doesnt-work-in-android)

Comment: Hovering requires support from the hardware. The only thing likely to support it is a stylus. It won't work with just your finger.

Comment: I said on android emulator and not with my fingers, using mouse i tried.

Comment: I don't want to work it on any device i just want it to work on emulator, so thats y i posted this. Please check the post i have mentioned " android emulator" and hovered mouse over it.